# DSum Query in Access Results in #Name? and/or #Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

I have a query, "RequestTimeEstimates_WorkQueue_Q" that will result in data similar to the following:

```
RequestID   OrigRequestID   Queue   TotalEstTime    RemainEstTime
87          87              1       119             8
97          97              2       14              13
99          99              3       48              48
```

I have a form that used this query as the control source.

On the form, I am displaying the `Queue` value for a given record. I would also like to display the sum of `RemainEstTime` for this record and all records with a `Queue` value less than this record. The best way to do this I would assume is a DSum, so I created the equation below and set it as the control source for my "Total Remaining Time" textbox.

Here is the DSum equation I used as the control source:

```
=DSum("RemainEstTime",
"RequestTimeEstimates_WorkQueue_Q",
"[Queue]=<" & [Forms]![API_Request_ViewProgress_subF_Queue]![Queue])
```

The result when viewing the form however is:

> `#Name?`

I've tried a few changes to the expression, including adding [ ] around the query and field names of the DSum.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

---

### Side note

I have also tried doing this strictly as a query (which would almost be more preferable anyhow. Using the same query & results above, I tried this:

```
SELECT 
RequestTimeEstimates_WorkQueue_Q.*, 
DSum([RequestTimeEstimates_WorkQueue_Q].RemainEstTime],
"RequestTimeEstimates_WorkQueue_Q",
"[Queue]=<" & [Queue]) AS QueueTimeRemaining 
FROM 
RequestTimeEstimates_WorkQueue_Q;
```

That results in a

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Queue]=<1'.

I assume that is because I'm referencing [Queue] twice, but I couldn't come up with a better option.

Again, any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It is `<=` not `=<`

Comment: @SunKnight0 - haha wow, can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you!